How to Optimize Cache Line Read Access with Minimal Writer Cache Impact on x86?
I'm working with an x86 processor and need to read data that resides in another processor's cache line. I am coding in C++. The data is initially in an Exclusive (E) or Modified (M) state in the owner’s cache, and when I read it, it transitions to a Shared (S) state. Data resides in a single cache line.
My main concern is that the owner’s performance may decrease because, while writing, it must first signal all other processors to invalidate their caches as the data transitions from a Shared (S) state to a Modified (M) state. I want to ensure that my repeated reads don't significantly affect the owner’s cache performance by causing unnecessary invalidation traffic.
Currently, I am polling the cache line repeatedly to check for updates. However, I'm worried this approach might lead to performance degradation for the owner due to frequent invalidation signals.
Is there a more efficient method to handle this situation? Specifically:
How can I minimize the performance impact on the owner when I repeatedly read the cache line?
Are there any architectural or programming techniques available on x86 to optimize cache line read access and minimize invalidation traffic?
I'm looking for strategies or methods that can help me achieve efficient cache line reads while ensuring minimal interference with the owner’s cache operations.

I don't think you can do that. If you have one core constantly writing to a cache line and another core constantly reading same cache line, that cache line is going to constantly bounce between the cores, and the performance will be affected. Usual solution to this is to reduce frequency of the accesses for one of the cores in order to decrease rate of bouncing.

Perhaps MOVNTDQ will do what you want. It loads the cache line into  a temporary internal buffer without filling the data to the cache. The memory type needs to be WC on the processor snooping the line and WB on the processor writing the line.
